# How to mmap a slice of X in Go?

Tags: go, mmap

I'm trying to use `launchpad.net/gommap` to memory map an array of `int32`, and some other custom struct types. I strictly want to use them where they are in the mapped region. The `gommap.Mmap` type is `[]byte`, how can I make sections of that available as slices of some other type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use the unsafe package.

```
func mapInt32(fd uintptr, prot gommap.ProtFlags, flags gommap.MapFlags) ([]int32, error) {
    mmap, err := gommap.Map(fd, prot, flags)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    header := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&mmap))
    // account for the size different between byte and int32
    header.Len /= 4
    header.Cap = header.Len
    return *(*[]int32)(unsafe.Pointer(header)), nil
}
```

You may want to make a way to unmap the memory when you're done with it. You could do that by unsafely casting your `[]int32` back to a `gommap.MMap` in a similar way.

Comment: You've made `header.Cap = header.Len`, despite the fact those are already equal when `gommap.Map` returns. Did you do this to avoid doing the division by 4 again?

Comment: You could divide `header.Cap` too. One way or another it should be equal to `header.Len`.

Comment: Thanks! That's the clarification I needed. I'll try this answer and mark it the solution if it works.